# How to access values inside an array which hass been returned from a function in another class

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a function inside another class which produces values and stores all these values inside an array. I have then returned this array as I need to return an item. I have done a println at the end of the function which looks like `System.out.println(outputArray[1]);` to see if the values are being stored and it does return the correct value. This value is 3.68.

However when I try to access the array from another class I am just getting 1 value of 0 back instead of all the values stored inside the array. I did the `System.out.println(outputArray[1]);` again inside that other class and it produced 0 instead of 3.68.

Why is it not accessing and returning the value from the array which is stored at that index which comes from the function?

I think it has something to do with me not accessing the returned array from that function. I will use these values inside this other class to plot on a graph once I have solved this probem.

```
public class GetResults{

public double[] tableOfresults() {
    double[] outputArray = new double[100];

    for(int i = 0; i<100; i++) {

       //At this point I calculate results and store them in the array using i as the index of the array

    }
    System.out.println(outputArray[1]); // produces 3.68 here
    return outputarray;


public class graph{
    getResults gr
    public XYSeries inputOutputGraph() {
        XYSeries graph = new XYSeries("My graph");
        XYDataset xyDataset = new XYSeriesCollection(graph);
        System.out.println(GetResults.outputArray[1];) //Its produces 0 here
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
            "Graph", "Time", "results",
            xyDataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
        ChartFrame graphFrame = new ChartFrame("XYLine Chart", chart);
        graphFrame.setVisible(true);
        graphFrame.setSize(300, 300);
        return graph;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Probably because you are not accessing the right array. It is impossible to answer your question without seeing the relevant code or, even better, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Please post example code!

Comment: @user2041029 I updated my answer. Could you check if it works or not?

Answer (score 0):

I see at least three errors:

1. the curly braces are not correct
2. `getResults gr` should probably be `GetResults gr` (typo when copy-pasting? that is strange...)
3. You call `GetResults.outputArray[1];` but `outputArray` is defined inside the method. If your code compiles, that means that you also have a `static` variable in your class with the same name, and this explains the behavior.

I assume that what you want to do is

```
gr.tableOfresults()[1];
```

Note that you will have to change `getResults gr` to

```
GetResults gr = new GetResults();
```

for it to work

---

The other possibility is that you want to have `tableOfresults` function defined as `static`, and call it as follows

```
 GetResults.tableOfresults()[1];
```

In this case, the line `getResults gr` is not needed, but you should change `public double[] tableOfresults() {` to

```
public static double[] tableOfresults() {
```

Note that this will not compile if you access non-static variables form the `tableIfresults` function.

---

The third case, which I think is a bit weird, is if you want to actually call a static variable from the other class. In this case, you should leave the `GetResults.outputArray[1];` as is, but do the following changes:

`getResults gr` should become

```
(new GetResults).tableOfresults();
```

and `return outputarray;` should become

```
GetResults.outputarray = outputarray;
```

add the declaration of outputArray inside the GetResults class

```
public static double[] outputArray
```

---

Fourth possibility is that you want to call a static variable, and also make the `tableOfresults()` static. In this case you want `GetResults.outputArray[1];` unchanged, but you need:

`getResults gr` should become

```
GetResults.tableOfresults();
```

and `return outputarray;` should become

```
GetResults.outputarray = outputarray;
```

`public double[] tableOfresults() {` should become

```
public static double[] tableOfresults() {
```

add the declaration of outputArray inside the GetResults class

```
public static double[] outputArray
```